# Converting a table text file to csv in Perl

Tags: csv, perl

I have a file that contains a list of things in fixed-width record format such as...

```
Name        Lastyear Weight      Thisyear Weight
Alice       130                  135
Bob         170                  165
Chris       190                  210
Daniel      195                  185 
Eric        150                  170
```

I want to convert this into a csv file. I know that I can make use of Text::CVS_XS to this but I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around it. I've seen lots of exaxmples of text to cvs but none where the text is already in a table format. Does that mean, I will have to change it from table format and add commas in between? Or does Text::CVS do that for me?

```
open my $file1, '<', $a or die $!;

chomp $file1;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

while(<$file1>){
#table to csv code 
}

$csv->eol ("\r\n");
    open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "table.csv" or die "Couldn't open 'table.csv': $!";

    $csv->print ($fh, $_);
    close $fh;
    close $file1;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "table format"?

Comment: Actual sample data that is representative of your actual data would help. Are there spaces in your column? How are columns separated? Hard to tell from just a bunch of dots.

Comment: @Shawn Sorry about that! Was trying to keep it simple so I could take the idea and then apply it to my work on a larger scale. The columns are separated by spaces. printf is used with "%-*s %*s %*s\n",

Comment: @sfr Can the fields contain spaces?

Comment: @melpomene The answer below correcting my choice of words. What I meant is "fixed-width record format". Yes, they can contain spaces if there is supposed to be a blank field in one of the columns

Comment: What do you mean by "a blank field in one of the columns"?

Comment: @melpomene For example, assume I have an entry for David along with his age, but I don't have his weight, I will leave a blank entry for his weight.

Comment: That's not what I was asking. Please show actual sample data that we can work with.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not able to disclose actual sample data from the scripts I'm working with so I am trying my best to come up with solutions based off answers and comments. I understand it's quite vague and confusing without actual data. :/

Comment: So create equivalent sample input. Change letters to other letters, numbers to other numbers, etc.

Comment: @melpomene I just updated my example and that's essentially just how my data looks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean fixed-width record format.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS qw();
open my $in, '<', 'so-57352269.txt';
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'table.csv';
my @column_widths = (6, 5, 6);
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({binary => 1, auto_diag => 1});
while (my $line = $in->getline) {
    chomp $line;
    my $pack_format = join '', map { "a$_" } @column_widths;
    my @record = unpack $pack_format, $line;
    $csv->say($out, \@record);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction :) I'm not able to use say which I'm assuming might be due to my version of perl. I tried it with print but that entirely mixes up the output. i wonder if that is due to me using print or because using defined column widths.